# Exception 'HDFStore requires PyTables ' when using HDF5 file in iPython

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I am very new to Python and am trying to create a table in pandas with HDFStore as follows

```
store = HDFStore('store.h5')
```

I get the exception :

```
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Python27\<ipython-input-11-de3060b689e6> in <module>()
----> 1 store = HDFStore('store.h5')

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas-0.10.1-py2.7-win32.egg\pandas\io\pytables.pyc in __init__(self, path, mode, complevel, complib, fletcher32)
    196             import tables as _
    197         except ImportError:  # pragma: no cover
--> 198             raise Exception('HDFStore requires PyTables')
    199 
    200         self.path = path

Exception: HDFStore requires PyTables
```

I already have Pytables installed and it is present in site-packages. Both pandas(0.l0.1) and pytables(2.4.0) are 32 bit Windows versions. Python version is 2.7.3 for 32 bit windows

I am running this using ipython notebook.

I forgot to add that I have Windows 7 - 64 bit OS, but Python and all its related add-ons are 32 bit.

Comment: What happens if you run `import tables`?

Comment: It throws an Import Error: `ImportError                               Traceback (most       recent call last)
    C:\Python27\<ipython-input-12-389ecae14f10> in <module>()
    ----> 1 import tables

    C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tables\__init__.py in <module>()
         67 
     68 # Necessary imports to get versions stored on the cython extension

---> 69 from tables.utilsExtension import getPyTablesVersion, getHDF5Version
      70 
      71 

    ImportError: cannot import name getPyTablesVersion`

Comment: I forgot to add that I have Windows 7 - 64 bit OS, but Python and all related add-ons are 32 bit, could that be an issue ?

Comment: I don't think so. How did you install pytables? Are you sure everything is compiled? You could try to use one of the setup files [from here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pytables).

Comment: Thank you, I went back and realized that I have not compiled it correctly as I do not have the HDF5 library installed.

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same error when using **HDFStore**. And I tried all the steps specified above and spent many hours to find a solution, but non of them were successful.

Then I downloaded and installed [MiniConda](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html). And then I used the below command to install pytables.

```
conda install -c conda-forge pytables
```

Please refer the below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your problem is that you have not added Python Scripts to your system `PATH`. Assuming that check out [this tutorial](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/command_line.shtml#environment-variables) on how to do it.

You are looking to add the `C:\Python27, C:\Python27\Lib. and C:\Python27\Scripts`. Make sure you separate each one with a `;`. Also make sure you add it to your system `PATH` variable and not just your user `PATH` variable.

after all of that check `import pytables`. It should no longer throw and error, because python will be 'know' that pytables is installed and be able to locate it.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.  I am using win7 + anaconda python2.7 + IPython.

But I fixed it with following steps:

From  http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pytables
download file tables‑3.2.1‑cp27‑none‑win_amd64.whl

and install it with cmd

```
pip install tables‑3.2.1‑cp27‑none‑win_amd64.whl
```

after installed problem solved.

ref: http://www.pytables.org/usersguide/installation.html#binary-installation-windows