# How to convert a saved Keras .h5 file to csv file or .mat file

Tags: python, keras

I trained a classifier model using keras then I saved the architecture of the model in a H5 file and the weights in Json file. 
I was wondering how can I convert the H5 file into any other file like .csv or .mat? 
And how can I load  after that the model architecture with these files?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.HDFStore.select.html

Answer (score 1):

http://curlybrackets.co/blog/2017/06/06/using-python-dump-hdf5-h5-files-csv/

```
import pandas as pd

with pd.HDFStore('myfile.h5', 'r') as d:
    df = d.get('TheData')
    df.to_csv('myfile.csv')
```

Comment: Do you mean by 'TheData' the content in the h5 file (in my case the model architecture) ?

Comment: I tried it and I get this error message                                                                                                                     'importing'.format(ex=str(ex)))

ImportError: HDFStore requires PyTables, "DLL load failed: La procédure spécifiée est introuvable." problem importing                                                       However i nstall Tables using pip install Tables

Comment: Maybe try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469594/exception-hdfstore-requires-pytables-when-using-hdf5-file-in-ipython

Comment: Ok it fixed the error message but still I don't get what should I put in  'TheData' my code part is                                                   classifier.save_weights('model_weights.h5')
# Save the model architecture
with open('model_architecture.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(classifier.to_json())